# MySQL Recursively get all parent values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table which is as follows:

```
id  parent_id
1   0
7   1
10  7
15  10
19  15
23  19
```

When i provide an id , i should get all the parent values for that id in one query

For e.g:

```
for 23, the result should be 19, 15, 10, 7 & 1
for 19, the result should be 15, 10, 7 & 1
for 15, the result should be 10, 7 & 1
for 10, the result should be 7 & 1
for 7, the result should be 1
for 1, the result should be empty
```

Will the following work?

```html
create table my_table (
    `id` int,
    `parent_id` int
); 
insert into my_table (`id`, `parent_id`) values(1,NULL);
insert into my_table (`id`, `parent_id`) values(2,1);
insert into my_table (`id`, `parent_id`) values(3,2);
insert into my_table (`id`, `parent_id`) values(4,3);
insert into my_table (`id`, `parent_id`) values(5,4);
insert into my_table (`id`, `parent_id`) values(6,5);
insert into my_table (`id`, `parent_id`) values(31,6);

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(T2.id) AS my_data
FROM (
    SELECT
        @r AS _id,
        (SELECT @r := parent_id FROM my_table WHERE id = _id) AS parent_id,
        @l := @l + 1 AS lvl
    FROM (SELECT @r := 2, @l := 0) vars, my_table m
    WHERE @r <> 0) T1
JOIN my_table T2
ON T1._id = T2.id
ORDER BY T1.lvl ASC;
```

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using? It makes quite a difference in what can be done, query wise.

Comment: I am using 5. i would like to have a query that works for 5 and 8

Comment: In MySQL 5.x there is not possibility to solve the task in single query form (except the case when maximal output nested level is set). Use iterative stored procedure.

Comment: You can't do by single query but can make a procedure

Comment: Do you have a sample procedure that i can use?

Comment: *Will the following work?* The code is synthactically correct. But it is incorrect logically and may produce `ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row`. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=46a63f21fc9040188e1c909ae63e0c53 Neither PK nor ORDER BY will help - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ca12a19bc930bea6748833f1d4893daf Maybe `CHECK (id>parent_id)` can - but not supported on 5.7.

Comment: its working when i try "SELECT @r := 5". OR "SELECT @r := 4", Do yo know why?

Answer (score 2):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE get_tree ()
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE tmp (id INT, parent_id INT, path VARCHAR(255)) ENGINE = Memory;
INSERT INTO tmp SELECT id, parent_id, CONCAT(id, ',', parent_id) FROM test;
REPEAT
    UPDATE tmp 
    JOIN test ON tmp.parent_id = test.id
    SET tmp.parent_id = test.parent_id, path = CONCAT(tmp.path, ',', test.parent_id);
UNTIL NOT ROW_COUNT() END REPEAT;
SELECT id, test.parent_id, tmp.path
FROM tmp 
JOIN test USING (id);
DROP TABLE tmp;
END
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b4d92417d8b7e81b2b28641139b37d49

If trailing `',0'` not needed then cut it off in final SELECT. For long paths adjust `path VARCHAR(255)` and increase its length (or use TEXT datatype).

**Caution!** The data must not contain cycles! If there is a cycle then the procedure will work infinitely and may hang the server. For to avoid this add UDV-counter which restricts max. amount of iterations.

---

> Would you mind adding a logic to prevent cycles? The stored proc can exit whenever it finds data in loops – Ann

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE get_tree ()
BEGIN
DECLARE max_iterations INT DEFAULT 100;
CREATE TABLE tmp (id INT, parent_id INT, path VARCHAR(255)) ENGINE = Memory;
INSERT INTO tmp SELECT id, parent_id, CONCAT(id, ',', parent_id) FROM test;
REPEAT
    SET max_iterations = max_iterations - 1;
    SELECT max_iterations;
    UPDATE tmp 
    JOIN test ON tmp.parent_id = test.id
    SET tmp.parent_id = test.parent_id, path = CONCAT(tmp.path, ',', test.parent_id);
UNTIL NOT ROW_COUNT() OR NOT max_iterations END REPEAT;
SELECT id, test.parent_id, tmp.path
FROM tmp 
JOIN test USING (id);
DROP TABLE tmp;
END
```

Comment: thanks a lot Akina. Would you mind adding a logic to prevent cycles? The stored proc can exit whenever it finds data in loops

Comment: @Ann Answer updated. The amount of loops is restricted with 100. You may not declare/hardcode it but provide as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks Akina. I added another answer above without SP. Please check if it is ok